# C sscanf (fscanf) behaving differently row from row

Tags: c, scanf

I've this snippet of code which should read text from input file and put it in a struct.

```c
void load(FILE *fin, struct camion payload[]){
        int i=0;
        char except;
        char buf[1000];
        while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fin)){
                except='A';
                sscanf(buf,"%i-%i-%i %i %s %c",&payload[i].day,&payload[i].    month,&payload[i].year,&payload[i].nparcels,payload[i].origin,&except);
                if (except=='E')
                        payload[i].except=1;
                i++;
        }
}
```

The fgets works as it should (tested it), but the fscanf starting with this file:

```
01-01-2013      354     hub_J
01-01-2013      109     hub_L
03-01-2013      129     hub_J
04-01-2013      265     hub_J
08-01-2013      488     hub_B
09-01-2013      127     hub_J
09-01-2013      136     hub_K
09-01-2013      97      hub_D
10-01-2013      369     hub_O
11-01-2013      455     hub_G
12-01-2013      125     hub_I   E
13-01-2013      105     hub_O
13-01-2013      468     hub_C
13-01-2013      360     hub_H   E
```

returns (the printing function is not the problem, the problem happens right when the sscanf is executed) this:

```
1- 1-2013 354 hub_J  
1- 1-2013 109 hub_L  
3- 1-2013 129 hub_J  
4- 1-2013 265 hub_J  
0- 0-   0 0   
0- 0-   0 0   
0- 0-   0 0   
0- 0-   0 0   
10- 1-2013 369 hub_O  
11- 1-2013 455 hub_G  
12- 1-2013 125 hub_I E
13- 1-2013 105 hub_O  
13- 1-2013 468 hub_C  
13- 1-2013 360 hub_H E
```

The rows with E mean oversize payload, thus E is not always present, but this shouldn't be the error.
I'm banging my head against the wall.
thanks in advance

Comment: also, always check for the return value of `scanf()` family.

Comment: @user3121023 please post is as answer so that I can mark it as right.

Comment: @NatashaDutta thanks, I was not sure in this case since return value can differ based on the row which is being scanned

Comment: I don't think your `scanf` will work for lines that don't have `E` at the end. There's nothing for the last `%c` to match.

Comment: VirtualFlyer hope @Barmar's comment made it clear. it's bad but you can use two `scanf()`s with different format specifiers (including and excluding last `%c`)

Comment: Yes indeed, I will. Anyways since if I used fscanf that wouldn't work (it would replace it with the first char in the next line), with fgets and sscanf it does work, even though I know it's very ugly and not smart.

Comment: strongly suggest check the returned value from the sscanf() to determine exactly how many entries were input/converted by the sscanf() then make use of that returned value in the following processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scanning with `%i` and values with a leading zero are assumed to be octal. `08` and `09` are not octal values. Use `%d` instead as leading zero's are ignored and values are in base 10.
For the sscanf you might try this. It will scan the five items present in all the lines. The `%n` specifier will give you the characters processed by the scan. You can then test `buf[offset]`. If a newline is there, then the entire string was processed. Otherwise there is more to the string and a second sscanf can capture the remaining character.
Disclaimer: I have not compiled and tested this code.

```
void load(FILE *fin, struct camion payload[]){
    int i=0;
    int offset=0;
    char except;
    char buf[1000];
    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fin)){
        except='A';
        if ( ( sscanf(buf,"%d-%d-%d %d %s%n"
        ,&payload[i].day
        ,&payload[i].month
        ,&payload[i].year
        ,&payload[i].nparcels
        ,payload[i].origin
        ,&offset)) == 5) {
            if ( buf[offset] != '\n') {
                sscanf(buf+offset, " %c", &except);
            }
        }
        if (except=='E') {
            payload[i].except=1;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```